# HTML Table's TD not aligning top

Tags: html, css

I am just trying out a simple table format but it's been giving me headache

[image]

The table has a fixed height, and the items is supposed to be aligned to the top. With empty spaces below if there is excess space.

Current Code

```
<table width='100%' height='250px' style='font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; border: 1.0pt solid windowtext; vertical-align: top;'>
<tr style='border-bottom: 1.0pt solid windowtext;'>
    <td><b><u>Sim Card :</u></b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><b>Phone Number</b></td>
    <td><b>4G</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>55555555</td>
    <td>YES</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>66666666</td>
    <td>YES</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>77777777</td>
    <td>NO</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

EDIT:

I think i wasn't clear with what I want earlier, what I want is not just for the TD to valign top, its for the whole cell to be valigned to the top of the table without each of them having the average height of the table.

[image]

Comment: Why don't u try  for <td  valign="top"> ?

Comment: You are asking for top align. Or you want less space like this ? https://jsfiddle.net/wgrLfxg3/14/

Comment: May be a nested table with margin,padding as 0px created under main table's which will have single <tr> single <td colspan="2" style="vertical-align: top">

Comment: accept an answer if it helped you, or the bounty is going be wasted (you'll still loose it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks exactly like you want in your second picture:

```
<div style='width: 100%; height: 250px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; border: 1.0pt solid windowtext;'>
    <table width='100%'>
        <tr style='border-bottom: 1.0pt solid windowtext;'>
            <td><b><u>Sim Card:</u></b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Phone Number</b></td>
            <td><b>4G</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>55555555</td>
            <td>YES</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>66666666</td>
            <td>YES</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>77777777</td>
            <td>NO</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/83drLumk/2/

Answer (score 3):

You may as well reset tr display unless you have some colspan involved wich might need tuning to be done.

```css
tr{
  display:table;
  width:100%;
  table-layout:fixed;
}
```

```html
<table width='100%' height='250px' style='font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; border: 1.0pt solid windowtext; vertical-align: top;'>
<tr style='border-bottom: 1.0pt solid windowtext;'>
    <td><b><u>Sim Card :</u></b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><b>Phone Number</b></td>
    <td><b>4G</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>55555555</td>
    <td>YES</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>66666666</td>
    <td>YES</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>77777777</td>
    <td>NO</td>
</tr>
  <tr><td style="text-align:center; background:#eee">add more content and rows to let that table grow itself once bottom reached</td></tr>
</table>
```

Since answer is already given, mind it as an alternative

---

another answers says: add empty elements, wich actually is a good tip too, but via :after it wouldn't bother the markup.

```css
tr {
  height:1%;
  }
table:after {
  content:'';
  display:table-row;
  }
```

```html
<table width='100%' height='250px' style='font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; border: 1.0pt solid windowtext; vertical-align: top;'>
<tr style='border-bottom: 1.0pt solid windowtext;'>
    <td><b><u>Sim Card :</u></b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><b>Phone Number</b></td>
    <td><b>4G</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>55555555</td>
    <td>YES</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>66666666</td>
    <td>YES</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>77777777</td>
    <td>NO</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply vertical align value to the `<td>` element

```
td {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Also noticed you should add `colspan` on the only `<td>`, in first `<tr>`

```
<td colspan="2" style='vertical-align: top;'>
    <b><u>Sim Card :</u></b>
</td>
```

**Edit:**

Just saw  you updated question. You can just create some empty cell and add them before the end of the table. Also remove the `height` value on the table.

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        &nbsp;
    </td>
</tr>
```

Updated demo http://jsfiddle.net/q8e78cL0/

**Edit 2:**

[@GCyrillus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28992892/483779) also pointed out a better way by using pseudo element to create the blank space, so no need to touch the markup.

```
table:after {
    content: '';
    display: table-row;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Demo here http://jsfiddle.net/q8e78cL0/2/

Answer (score 2):

The vertical-align CSS property in not inherited by default. Apply the `vertical-align: top` property to the `td` elements directly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct way

```
<table width='100%' height='250px' style='font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; border: 1.0pt solid windowtext; vertical-align: top;'>
<tr style='border-bottom: 1.0pt solid windowtext;'>
    <td><b><u>Sim Card :</u></b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><b>Phone Number</b></td>
    <td><b>4G</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>55555555</td>
    <td>YES</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>66666666</td>
    <td>YES</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>77777777</td>
    <td>NO</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And here is a working demo fiddle for you. Just copy and paste the demo css and html

https://jsfiddle.net/wgrLfxg3/13/

Comment: it looks the same as my image from my computer

Comment: Or if you preffer set to each TD the follow style="top:0;vertical-align: top;"

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment yet so I'll have to do it this way.

You're giving your table a fixed height, which is exactly what causes the thing you want to remove. The auto calculated height of your rows. If I were you I would remove that table height and put a div around the table with a fixed height to give you the border you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
td {
    vertical-align: top;
    line-height: 2.0 !important
    }
```

Comment: This answer would be more useful if you explained how your code works and why it answers the question.

Comment: Line height is the space between the first line and your second line. the more you reduce it the more close your lines will print. Learn more about styling tables with css from https://www.google.co.zm/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fcss%2Fcss_table.asp&ei=iysFVYW3B87iapuegLgN&usg=AFQjCNFwp2YaT17OW2XCh_7T7T-M11n5pA&bvm=bv.88198703,d.d2s